# How to display Org Mode-like link descriptions in lieu of link in Gnus messages

Tags: emacs, gnus

I'd like to display inline link descriptions in my Gnus messages instead of the full hyperlink itself. This would be similar to how links display in Org Mode by writing `[[http://www.example.com/][example]]`. Is this possible, or does this conflict with the very nature of plain text messages? Is there a 'simple' workaround?

As a side note, I've noticed how most email clients I've used in the past (e.g., Thunderbird) have this functionality in some form, but the simple SMS/IM client Messages (Apple platform) won't allow link descriptions. I'm assuming this is related to the limitations I'm having with plain text messages in Gnus. Some light shed on my ignorance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think when you get an HTML mail, this behavior is right there already, so I guess you're mostly asking about text mails. I think while the display part in Gnus should be feasible (sounds like just another [washing function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Washing-Mail.html) to me), the bigger problem is whether you'll receive any text mails which will contain links of the form that you desire? In other words, if I get a normal text email, all I typically get by the sender is just the bare link, no descriptive text whatsoever.

Comment: Come to think of it, are you talking about _generating_ mails via `message` or are you talking about _displaying_ articles in Gnus?

Comment: Ahh, good point--I guess that distinction completely slipped my mind. I'm referring to generating mails via `message`. My apologies for the confusion! Will this functionality require that I send mail in HTML rather than plain text? I'm hoping there's a way to do this in plain text, although this probably defeats the point of _plain_ text.

Comment: Even if there is some minor mode (e.g., Org) that could provide this desired appearance, the mail would still need to be sent in HTML for the recipient to see this effect, correct?

Comment: Yes. I don't see any other way.